# What is the name of the variant of ICP where the correspondence of the points are known?

Tags: algorithms

Traditional ICP assumes that the inputs are point clouds with no predefined correspondences between the clouds.

If I know before hand that some / all points in one point cloud corresponds to some / all points in the other point cloud, I assume this becomes an easier problem to solve.

What is the name of this modified version of [point set registration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_set_registration) and what are some algorithms that solves this?

Comment: Can you please what ICP is, and ask your question more specifically? Rather than "what are some algorithms?" try to ask "I have tried this algorithm but stuck here."

Answer (score 1):

This problem is called "rigid registration", the correspondences being the "rigid" part.

As D.W. pointed out, you can do a least squares fit (or use something like RANSAC to find the correspondences and then do a least squares fit). In the absence of noise, the least squares fit has a particularly nice formulation which has been known for a long time.

If $\mathbf{x}_i$ and $\mathbf{y}_i$ are the two corresponding sets of coordinates (there are $n$ points), we want to find the rotation matrix $R$ and translation vector $\mathbf{t}$ which minimises:

$$\hbox{arg min} \frac{1}{n}\sum_i \left\Vert \mathbf{y}_i - R \mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{t}\right\Vert^2 $$

Calculate the covariance matrix:

$$\mathbf{\mu}_x = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \mathbf{x}_i$$
$$\mathbf{\mu}_y = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \mathbf{y}_i$$
$$\Sigma_{xy} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i (\mathbf{y}_i - \mathbf{\mu}_y) (\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{\mu}_x)^\intercal$$

Compute the singular value decomposition of the covariance matrix:

$$\Sigma_{xy} = U S V^\intercal$$

Then:

$$R = V U^\intercal$$

This algorithm [can be made more robust in the presence of noise](http://ssm.me.wisc.edu/reading/umeyama.pdf). There are also [more recent algorithms which are competitive](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1806.00627.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

If you have know the correspondence between all points, the problem becomes much easier.  You can find a homography using least squares, or a robust version such as [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus).  See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/10441104/781723, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/494238/14578.

If you know the correspondence for some points, you could derive a homography using just those points.  Or, you could modify an existing algorithm that assumes no correspondence to hard-code in that correspondence.  Usually existing algorithms first try to find a few candidate correspondences, then estimate a homography for each, then take the best.  When inferring a candidate correspondence, you can just force the known points to correspond to each other and infer only the rest.